# How do I overlay individual data points in a boxplot in R?

Tags: r, boxplot, jitter

This is my code:

```
boxplot(PhysData, main="PhysData", col= c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "lightblue", "royalblue", "purple", "pink")))
```

It has 8 columns of data (basically 4 sets of 2). But I want to include the individual data points to the boxplot (so I don't want to change anything about the boxplot, just adding all the other data points on top).

I'm working in Rstudio if that changes anything from R. And I'm very beginner so please explain every detail even if you think it's obvious!

I've tried looking at other questions on here about similar things, but I can't find one that explains exactly what I'm trying to do. I don't want random data added (which is what my impression of the jitter function is), but the actual data collected. Also most of what I've found use `ggplot()` instead of boxplot(). Is there a difference (and with `geom_boxplot`) and what is it?

Comment: It will be easy to help you out if you can provide the `PhysData` in `dput()` format and also add the libraries you are using. Please visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: jitter doesn't add random data, it jitters randomly to show all the points per group, so they don't plot on top of each other, see this post for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73311099/680068

Comment: Hi! Welcome on Stack Overflow. A similar question that can help you understand jitter has been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31630045/19487551

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `ggplot::geom_boxplot()` instead of `base::boxplot()`.

The `jitter` function does not add random data but spaces the existing data so you can see single data points without overlay. This [article](https://www.data-to-viz.com/caveat/boxplot.html) explains the use of `geom_boxplot()`. Code examples are also given.